# What is the Source of translations discrepancy in Gen. 8:4

Tags: genesis, textual-criticism, latin-vulgate

It looks like that in the Original Hebrew Gen 8:4, and in KJV for example, the date given is the *seventeenth* of the seventh month

> וַתָּנַח הַתֵּבָה בַּחֹדֶשׁ הַשְּׁבִיעִי, **בְּשִׁבְעָה-עָשָׂר יוֹם לַחֹדֶשׁ**, עַל, הָרֵי אֲרָרָט

> And the ark rested in the seventh month, **on the seventeenth day of the month**, upon the mountains of Ararat.

While in the Vulgate (and I think also in the Septuagint) the date mentioned is the twenty-seventh.

> requievitque arca mense septimo **vicesima septima die** mensis super montes Armeniae (Douay-Rheims English Translation: And the ark rested in the seventh month, the **seven and twentieth day** of the month, upon the mountains of Armenia.)

I wonder what is the source of the this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

Let us compere the following:

**Clementine text of Vulgate:**

- vigesimo septimo = 17th

**Jerome's Vulgate**:

- vicesima septima = 27th

**Septuagint**

- ἑβδόμῳ, ἑβδόμῃ = 27th

**Hebrew** is also 17th.

The DRB (Challoner) also has 27th.

Thus, it is the LXX and Jerome's Vulgate (and DRB) that appear at variance with the Hebrew